# How merge a branch that is behind master

Tags: git, github

How do I merge a branch that is behind master (with new commits) into master?

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO! Can you contextualize more your question and show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be rather simple:

```
git rebase --onto paper-version master GUI
```

So, rebase GUI branch, discard from rebase operation revisions that are part of the history of master branch, and put rebased revisions on top of paper-version.